# Gitlab pipeline - run the script with a rule

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to send a slack notification as soon as trigger the pipeline build manually.

Steps I am following:

1. Go to your project’s CI/CD > Pipelines and select Run pipeline.
2. Choose the branch you want to run the pipeline for.
3. Input the variable and its value in the UI.
4. Click on the `Run pipeline` button

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) I see:

> How the pipeline was triggered. Can be push, web, schedule, api, external, chat, webide, merge_request_event, external_pull_request_event, parent_pipeline, trigger, or pipeline. For a description of each value, see Common if clauses for rules, which uses this variable to control when jobs run.

In this `init` stage I want to execute a script only when I run the pipeline using the above steps

```
init:
  stage: init
  environment: $DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane slack_build_start_summary
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger" // also tried with "pipeline"
      when: always
```

But I can't see this stage in the Gitlab pipeline stages.

I want to know which `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` ("trigger" or "pipeline" or something else?) I need to check when I trigger the pipeline manually from Gitlab using the above steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer here from the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules)

> `web` -> For pipelines created by using Run pipeline button in the GitLab UI, from the project’s CI/CD > Pipelines section.

So I need to use:

```
- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
```